# Rails Looking for more efficient way of looping through records and displaying child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have the following controller action:

```
TeamController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @teams = Team.all
  end

end
```

Then on the index view I'm looping through all records and also displaying some information about child records for each team.

```
#/views/teams/index.slim

h1 pluralize(@teams.count, 'Team')
ul
  = render @teams

#/views/teams/_team.slim

li 
  span = team.name.titleize
  span = pluralize(team.members.count, 'member')
```

Here's the issue that stands out to me.  By calling `team.members` from the team partial it means that the server does a select query for each time the partial is called.  Obviously this is less than desirable outcome.

In the past I've tried:

```
TeamController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @teams = Team.all
      @members = Member.all
    end

  end
```

Then using `Array.select` in the partial like so:

```
#/views/teams/_team.slim

li
  span = team.name.titleize
  span = pluralize(@members.select{ |m| m.team_id == team.id }.count, 'member')
```

While this results in a much faster page render it puts more logic in the view than I would like. Additionally this approach easily breaks if `@members` is nil.

Has anyone faced this issue before?  What have you done to speed up the your list oriented index views?

Comment: ["Has anyone faced this issue before?"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rails+N%2B1+query)

Comment: @jvillian thanks for attaching the link, I wasn't aware there was a term for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal Rails solution to this is to "Eager Load" your associations like this:

```
def index
  @teams = Team.includes(:members).all
end
```

When this code actually fires off the SQL query, it will do 2 queries.
It will retrieve the teams with SQL (something) like this:

```
select * from teams
select * from members where id in (select member_id from teams)
```

And automatically stitch the data from the second query into the objects returned, so you can continue to call

```
= team.members.count
```

Without incurring the N+1 Query penalty every time this partial gets iterated over.

You can read more about [Eager Loading associations here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: Additionally, this gem claims to "automatically" remove the need to preload or eager load associations without changing your code at all. It might be worth a shot if that sounds appealing to you: https://github.com/clio/jit_preloader

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer!